# Is it hacky to manually construct JSON and manually handle GET, POST instead of using a proper RESTful API for AJAX functionality?

Tags: django, json, rest, restful-url, backbone.js

I started building a Django app, but this probably applies to other frameworks as well. In Backbone.js methods that call the server (fetch(), create(), destroy(), etc.), should you be using a proper RESTful API such as one provided by Tastypie or Django-Piston? I've founded it easier and more flexible to just construct the JSON in my Django Views, which are mapped to some URLs that Backbone.js can use. Then again, I'm probably not leveraging Tastypie/Django-Piston functionality to the fullest.

I'm not ready to make a full-fledged RESTful API for my app yet. I simply would like to use some of the AJAXy functionality that Backbone.js supports.

Pros/Cons of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Remember, REST does not equal JSON. If I require your representation in `text/html`, you should be able to provide me with that, or else throw a 415.

A better solution, then you are currently using, is to use the middleware functionality that Django provides. Whatever your view replies, use Djangos middleware functionality for the response to encode into JSON, XML or whatever.

Comment: i like your idea of adding any necessary transformations in middleware. it provides a single translation layer where everything can be encoded...i think i will try this and see how it works out. thanks!

Comment: @kliao, It's very simple. You can easily get the content type via `request.META["HTTP_ACCEPT"].split(",")[0]`, keep a source of supported types somewhere, using an if-condition check if it's support and perform the necessary operation.

Comment: You can modify the Backbone.sync function to process something else then JSON if needed. It currently does a JSON.stringify, but you can implement a XML, urlencoded or whatever your application works with the best.

Comment: You want 406 (Not Acceptable), not 415 (Unsupported Media Type) (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer defining my own ajax views and json objects. Using some already apis developed may be or may not be of much use. Some don't exactly fulfill the requirements some may have features which are redundant (And I don't like a code to be present which is not being used).

Also writing ajax functionality is not that difficult either. The inbuilt `serializers` / `request.is_ajax` features are there for your help.
Some examples for ajax implementation with django/jquery: http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/ (You most probably have seen it already)